# Remove consecutive nodes in Single-Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Can anyone help me figure it out? I create a method called `remainingNodes()` in the `SingleLinkedList` class to count remaining nodes after removing all consecutive nodes of same value in a single-linked list. However it didn't work the way it should have worked:
If there are multiple ways to remove nodes, remove the leftmost node.

[1,2,2,3,3,1] -> [1,3,3,1] -> [1,1] ->[] returns 0
[1,2,3,4,5,6] returns 6
[1,2,3,2,2,1] -> [1,2,3,1] returns 4
[1,2,2,2,3,1] -> [1,2,3,1] returns 4

```
public int remainingNodes(){
    Node curr = start;
    
    while (curr != null && curr.next != null) {
        while(curr.value == curr.next.value){
            curr.next = curr.next.next;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    int count = 0;
    curr = start;
    while (curr != null) {
        count++;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I can just only remove one node of a consecutive pair and I also know it is because I only add the next node of my current node = the next node of the next node of current. However, I don't really know what else should I add to get it worked like my expectation.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. What is `SingleLinkedList`? What is `Node`? What is the actual problem you're facing? Do you get errors? Is the output not what you expect? What is your question?

Comment: ah actually I typed it wrong, it's singly linked list

Comment: Why don't you use a variable size to keep track of the number of nodes in the list.  When you add a node, you increment size.  When you remove a node, you decrement size.  So, size() will always return the number of nodes in the list.  ``int size() { return size;}``

Comment: Why should `[1,2,2,2,3,1] -> [1,2,3,1] returns 4` be true? Is there a reason why not all `2` should be removed? The description says *"removing all consecutive nodes of same value"*. To me those three `2` are consecutive and have the same value...

Comment: The reason is the task asks to remove the leftmode consecutive pair of nodes

Comment: So if you have 4 consecutive `2` will they all be removed? And if there are 5 of them, will one remain, or three?

Comment: Could you come back to this? Can you edit your question and add the expected outputs for [1,2,2,2,2,1] and [1,2,2,2,2,2,1]?

Comment: they are [] and [1,2,1] respectively

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems:

1. Missing null-pointer check for `curr.next = curr.next.next;`
2. No attempt to go backward or restart when you find a duplicate.

The first fix is easy. Change

```
    while (curr != null && curr.next != null) {
        while(curr.value == curr.next.value){
            curr.next = curr.next.next;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
```

To

```
    while (curr != null && curr.next != null) {
        while(curr.next != null && curr.value == curr.next.value){
            curr.next = curr.next.next;
        }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
```

The second problem is more involved. Let's look at your logic with the example `[1 1]`. If I understand you correctly, you want it to convert the list to `[]`, and return 0. I will use notation `->` to mean "references" and `NodeK(value, next)` to refer to nodes in memory.

0. Initialize: start -> Node1; curr -> Node1. Node1(1, Node2). Node2(1, null).
1. Outer loop check if curr and curr.next are not null. They are not.
2. Inner loop if check curr.value (1) is the same as curr.next.value (1). They are.
3. Inner loop sets curr.next to curr.next.next. This redefines Node1 as Node1(1, null). curr still references Node1.
4. Inner loop stops because curr.next is null.
5. Outer loop sets curr to null.
6. Outer loop stops because curr is null.

The result is that `start` -> Node1(1, null). So the list is `[1]` and the return value will be 1.

It looks like you've found some code online that replaces runs of duplicates to a single item. What you're looking for is logic that removes all of the entries, so that there are none left.

To do that, you need to look an extra level deep:

```
if (start == null) {
  return 0;
}

// Begin by checking if the start reference needs to change.
// Keep executing this until no changes are made.
boolean changed = false;
while (!changed) {
  changed = false;
  Node curr = start.next;
  while (curr != null && start.value == curr.value) {
    curr = curr.next;
    changed = true;
  }

  // If the start needs to change, update it to the first node whose value was different.
  if (changed) {
    start = curr;
  }
}

// Then proceed with the rest of the list in a similar manner.
changed = false;
while (!changed) {
  Node previous = start;
  while (previous != null) {
    changed = false;
    anchor = previous.next; 
    curr = anchor.next;
    while (curr != null && anchor.value == curr.value) {
      curr = curr.next;
      changed = true;
    }
   
    if (changed) {
      previous.next = curr;
    }
  }
}
```

That should get you started at least. There's some null checks that need to happen here, but the basic idea is what you need. You need to keep a reference to the previous node (or the start node) because you're getting rid of all of the duplicates.

Another bit that's missing is that in the case of inputs like `[1 2 2 1]` where you expect the result to be `[]`, you need to run the whole algorithm again from the start if there's any changes. You're probably better off taking the idea and putting it into a function, so that you can call it repeatedly, and so that the `start` case and `previous` cases don't have so much repetition.

Comment: Actually what the task asks is to remove consecutive pair of nodes in this linked list and if there are many ways to remove nodes, remove the leftmode first. I tried to use what you suggested but didn't really work or maybe I've applied it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would set aside the *counting* of the remaining nodes after nodes have been removed, as that is a trivial exercise. Let's focus on the node removals.

As you have discovered, this algorithm will need to be able to step back to nodes that were already visited in order to still remove them if needed.  The problem is that when you have already walked to a next neighbor node, there is no more reference to the node you came from.

An intuitive way to solve this is to use recursion, such that the recursive call does the job for the nodes *after* the current head node, and then after the recursion comes back the head can be compared with the first node in the list that was returned. If the same, both nodes are removed.

Here is how that would look:

```
    private Node recurRemove(Node head) {
        if (head != null) {
            head.next = recurRemove(head.next);
            if (head.next != null && head.next.value == head.value) {
                head = head.next.next; // Remove a twin
            }
        }
        return head;
    }

    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Node curr = start; curr != null; curr = curr.next) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    public int remainingNodes() {
        start = recurRemove(start);
        return size();
    }
```

This looks elegant in my humble opinion, but the downside is that it needs stack space, and that is limited.

Even if you would use an explicit stack as local variable instead, it is a pity that the algorithm would have an auxiliary space complexity of O().

### Solution with O(1) auxiliary space

We could make this work with O(1) auxiliary space by realising that the linked list itself can be used as a stack. This could be done with this algorithm:

- Start a new list (as empty)
- Keep taking nodes from the original list (making it shorter) and prepend those nodes one by one to that new list (as if it were a stack) until duplicate values are encountered.
- When that happens there is one of the twin nodes already on the "stack", while the second one is still the original (shortened) list. From that list remove pairs for as long as itself has twins at its start. Once that is done check if now the first remaining node still has the same value as the node already on the stack. If so pop the node from the stack and remove it from the original list as well.
- Repeat this process until the original list is empty.
- The "stack" is now the list we want to have but in reversed order.
- To get the list back in its intended order, repeat the above steps once more. This time no more nodes will be removed, but the list will be reversed still, which is the intention.

Here is an implementation:

```
    public int reverseAndRemoveTwins() {
        Node right = start;
        start = null; // We will prepend unique values to this (stack)
        int count = 0; // This time we will also keep a counter (size of stack)
        
        while (right != null) {
            Node next = right.next;
            if (start == null || start.value != right.value) {
                // Move the right node to become the head of the left list (reversal!)
                right.next = start;
                start = right;
                right = next;
                count++;
            } else {
                // Remove all identical values at the right
                boolean odd = false;
                while (right != null && start.value == right.value) {
                    right = right.next;
                    odd = !odd;
                }
                // ...and pop the one at the left too when an odd count was deleted
                if (odd) {
                     start = start.next;
                     count--;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int remainingNodes(){
        reverseAndRemoveTwins(); // This also reverses the list
        return reverseAndRemoveTwins(); // This reverses it back
    }
```

This code seems less elegant, but if you care about memory efficiency it is the way to go.

Comment: Did this work out for you? Any feedback?